# What WinDbg version is compatible with NT 4.0 (SP 6a) for kernel debug?

Tags: windbg, remote-debugging, kernel-mode

I'm working with WinDbg 6.12 with both serial port connection and named pipe connection. Unfortunately I'm unable to connect my WinDbg with the target (NT 4 SP 6a) from the begining of the OS boot, autoreconnect doesn't work and I need to wait until NT 4 timeout for kernel connection is reached. Then NT continues with the startup process and only then I can connect...

Where I can get a version fully compatible with NT 4? (I have already checked the oldest version from Microsoft Debugging Tools website)

Also, where can I get the NT 4 symbols for debugging? I'm afraid the Microsoft Symbols Server doesn't provide these symbols anymore.

Thanks,

For futher details, the kd log is:

```
Opened \\.\pipe\com_1
Waiting to reconnect...
Connected to Windows NT 4 1381 x86 compatible target at (Tue Jan 24 16:32:17.010 2012 (UTC + 1:00)), ptr64 FALSE
Kernel Debugger connection established.
Symbol search path is: srv*b:\out*o:\out*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for ntoskrnl.exe - 
CS descriptor lookup failed
Windows NT 4 Kernel Version 1381 UP Free x86 compatible
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0x80100000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0x80150b70
System Uptime: not available
The call to LoadLibrary(kdextx86) failed, Win32 error 0n2
    "El sistema no puede hallar el archivo especificado."
Please check your debugger configuration and/or network access.
Unable to get program counter
WaitForEvent failed
Unable to get program counter
0008:497a 0010            add     byte ptr [bx+si],dl
kd>
```

Comment: sounds like your debugger installation is not complete

Comment: I have debugged drivers in a few XP machines (laptops, desktops and Virtual Machines...), maybe the compatibility with NT4 is broken.

Answer (score 2):

Works with http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/debuggers/dbg_amd64_6.7.05.1.exe

From Windbg 6.12 help:
"Windows NT 4.0
Debugging Tools for Windows no longer supports the debugging of Windows NT 4.0 targets.

If you want to debug a Windows NT 4.0 target computer or perform user-mode debugging on Windows NT 4.0, you should use Debugging Tools for Windows version 6.7.5.1. You can install this package from the  Debugging Tools for Windows Web site."